# writing a state of a dynamical system

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

Is it un/common to write the state of a dynamical system in the following manner:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}x_{t+1} \\ v_{t+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_{t} \\ v_{t} \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}E & F \\ G & H \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p_{t} \\ q_{t} \end{pmatrix}$$

What could this form mean? And how could this impact the way we analyze the system? (For example, if we want to check stability, etc)

Your insights will help a lot.

Comment: Well, this reminds me about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability#Discrete_linear_time-invariant_.28LTI.29_systems . In your case the ${\rm x}(t)$ from Wikipedia is your $(x_{t+1}, v_{t+1})$.

Comment: I wonder how the analysis for stability would go for this kind of system? Also, would you know of non- time-invariant systems?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $p_t$ and $q_t$ are not states. So this equation is just

$$z_{t+1} = M z_t + N u_t$$

where $z_t := \begin{pmatrix}x_{t+1} \\ v_{t+1} \end{pmatrix}$, $u_t := \begin{pmatrix}p_{t} \\ q_{t} \end{pmatrix}$, $M := \begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}$ and $N := \begin{pmatrix}E & F \\ G & H \end{pmatrix}$. So the stability can be determined by checking the eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: I vaguely remember this form from linear control theory. So, the stability of the system is completely determined by $M$ only? And $N$ is, to say, not essential?

Comment: Yes, the stability is completely determined by $M$ only. $N$ may also be essential depending on what you want to achieve. Specifically, the controllability of the system are determined by $M$ and $N$, which may be essential.

Comment: Thanks. Please send me a reference where I can read further.

Comment: I don't have a specific reference in my mind but you can search for modern control theory and linear control theory textbooks.